# Orderer and committer taking time to put data into ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We are facing an issue related to putting data into the ledger. If we attempt to insert data into ledger and then immediately fetch the inserted data, we are not getting anything. If we request after 3 seconds or so, all seems good. Any solution to overcome this delay for best user experience?

Answer (score 2):

The trip that a transaction takes is:

1. Client (origin point)
2. Ordering service
3. Kafka cluster
4. Ordering service
5. Committing peer

Where:

- Stages 3 and 4 apply only if you're using the Kafka-based ordering service
- The transaction gets validated on Stage 5 before it is committed to the ledger

It is only after all of these stages have been completed that you can see the transaction committed to the ledger, so it is normal for the transaction to not show up instantaneously.

As for the 3-second delay, I suspect that this happens because your `Orderer.BatchTimeout` is set to the default of 2 seconds and you `Orderer.BatchSize.MaxMessageCount` is set to a value larger than 1 (the default is 10).

That means that the ordering service will not cut a block (and have it delivered to the committing peers) until *either* of these two conditions are met. You are sending less than `Orderer.BatchSize.MaxMessageCount` transactions, so the ordering service needs to wait `Orderer.BatchTimeout` seconds before it cuts the block.

In order to decrease the time it takes for the transaction to show up in your ledger, set `Orderer.BatchTimeout` to a small value (say, 1 ms), and `Orderer.BatchSize.MaxMessageCount` to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kostas

Comment: One thing I Can do is that after handover the data to orderer and committer for insertion into the ledger .I can fetch the data from couchdb .Because couchdb insert the data immediately into his document.
Is there any risk or drawback in this concept ? @kostas

Comment: Any piece of data that ends up in the blockchain has to go through the route I described above. This also applies to the CouchDB ledger. You are dealing with a system that is asynchronous, you should not have synchronous expectations from it. Use the event hub to be notified when the transaction makes it to the ledger, and work from there.